# is FTS available in the iOS build of SQLite?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I am interested in using the full text search capability of SQLite.

I understand it was not compiled in to the iPhone/iOS version.

Is this still the case?

Comment: I am not an expert with iPhone/iOS but would't it be possible to link your (FTS) enabled SQLite lib into your program? At least statically should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not available in the standard build of sqlite3 on iOS But you can still use it.

The best way to use it is to download the sqlite3 amalgamation and configure it for FTS3. Add the sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h file to your project and remove sqlite3 from your frameworks list on your application.

Statically adding it this way will work perfectly.

Comment: We use coredata in the project.  Am i going to have an issue if i remove sqlite3 from my project's frameworks?

Comment: Yes, you'll have a problem. Core Data pulls from the standard build of SQLite.

Comment: With iOS 10.2 (possibly much earlier), checking with `"PRAGMA compile_options;"` seems to indicate support: (
    "COMPILER=clang-8.0.0 (clang-800.2.34)",
    "ENABLE_API_ARMOR",
    "ENABLE_FTS3",
    "ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS",
    "ENABLE_JSON1",
    "ENABLE_LOCKING_STYLE=1",
    "ENABLE_RTREE",
    "ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT",
    "HAS_CODEC",
    "HAVE_ISNAN",
    "MAX_MMAP_SIZE=20971520",
    "OMIT_AUTORESET",
    "OMIT_BUILTIN_TEST",
    "OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION",
    "SYSTEM_MALLOC",
    "THREADSAFE=2"
)